Como quitar la cuenta de Google si perdí mis datos y no tengo acceso al interior del telefono
Solo me aparece acceder con una cuenta que aya sido registrada en el sistema android pero perdí todo tipo de información incluyendo el número

I’m voting to close this question because questions have to be written in English.
